# bivariate regression calculation?

Tags: regression, bivariate

I have been trying to follow the example available in this link about bivariate regression, page 4:

http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/MV/IntroMV.pdf

The univariate regression is easy to follow, the problem that I have is with the bivariate regression. In the univariate they put something like this:

[image]

for a data set of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

When they talk about bivariate regression they talk about a value of

> a value of X associated with each value of Y

and come up with the following scatter plot:

[image]

and they have a sum of squared residuals equal to:

-2.31, .30, .49, -.92, .89, -.53, and 2.08

The problem that I have is from where they got those values that are plotted on the scatter plot, I do not get it from the material.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: => are the values of the 2 $X_i$s on page 5 of the document you linked (along with the $Y_i$s too)? Is your question, how to fit a 2 variable  regression model to a given dataset?

Comment: thank you @LucasRoberts for your comment, I would like to know from where the residuals are calculated

Comment: I am familiar with using the following notation: "z = f(x, y)" so that if I have a single data point such as [X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3] the predicted value from the regression would be "pred = f(1, 2)" and error would be "pred - Z". For this example data point the error would be calculated as "pred - 3".

Comment: @Layla, do you understand how the "line of best fit" it calculated? To get the residuals first fit the regression line, call the point $(x_i, y_i)$ and the fitted value at $x_i$, $\hat{y}_i$ for the point $(x_i, \hat{y}_i)$ for the fitted value. Then each residual is $y_i - \hat{y}_i=r_i$. Check that the signs of the residuals match, o/w you might switch the order of the differencing.